# Java method that is similar to C++'s template functions

Tags: java

I wonder how to write a method in Java that is similar to C++ functions with `<typename T>`. The method I want to write is something like this:

```
class Program{
    private List<T> foo (List<T> list){
        List<T> list1 = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T i : list){
            //do something.
        }
        return list1;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with the one you've got?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `foo` is a generic method, you need to put `<T>` before the return type. The correct syntax is

```
private <T> List<T> foo (List<T> list){
    List<T> list1 = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T i : list){
        //do something.
    }
    return list1;
}
```

Comment: [Read more about Generics here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Comment: How do you call this method, pass 2 `List<Integer>`, and return a `List<Integer>`? I tried `Program p = new Program(); p.<Integer>foo (intList)` but it says the"parameterized method is not applicable for the arguments."